# EventWaitHandle.Close() - what type of call this is sync or Async?

Tags: c#

I have a EventWaitHandle to wait to receive some events. Once, I receive the event. I supposed to release all the resources used by the EventWaitHandle. For releasing the events am using EventWaitHandle.close().

My question is after calling this EventWaitHandle.Close(). Should I wait or sleep for some times to release all the resources?

Comment: you don't do either. you let it do its job and it will return once completed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.close.aspx. it implements Idisposable so it will release all resources once completed as per the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I will try the same.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, you mean when it is used with the using keyword?

Comment: @Silvermind - correct but I also am lead to believe that the call to Close() also releases the resources it has used as I quote from the documentation: "This method releases any unmanaged resources held by the current instance" and also "Use this method to release all resources held by an instance of WaitHandle". Reading the Dispose documentation for this class: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384809(v=vs.110).aspx" indicates it is equivalent to calling the Close method so I am therefore lead to believe the Close method will call Dispose

Comment: @Ahmedilyas It was sort of a retorical question, because the OP should implement the `EventWaitHandle` with a using statement. Thanks for the answer btw. More stuff to read for the OP ;)